# Bluetooth Stopped Working after Suspend 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, sound, bluetooth

I was using a bluetooth speaker this morning, hit suspend and left, and when I got back Bluetooth didn't work. The bluetooth settings menu now says "No Bluetooth Found". Bluetooth no longer works in windows either.

[No Bluetooth Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL5T3.png)

lspci:

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
>
> 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
>
> 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
>
> 00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
>
> 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
>
> 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
>
> 00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
>
> 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
>
> 00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
>
> 00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
>
> 00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
>
> 00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
>
> 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
>
> 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
>
> 00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
>
> 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1)
>
> 04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
>
> 05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)

rfkill list

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>
> Soft blocked: no
>
> Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep -i blue

> [    1.828853] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
>
> [    1.828861] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
>
> [    1.828863] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
>
> [    1.828865] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
>
> [    1.828867] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
>
> [    1.841683] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
>
> [    1.841685] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
>
> [    1.841686] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
>
> [    1.841687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
>
> [    1.841687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
>
> [    1.841688] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
>
> [    1.841704] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
>
> [    1.841711] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
>
> [    1.841711] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
>
> [   56.301728] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
>
> [   56.301730] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
>
> [   56.301732] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized